# base::file.choose(): cannot navigate to external drives

Tags: r

Using:

```
dir <- dirname(file.choose())
```

I get a window that starts on /home and cannot go upwards to select
external drives that are mounted on /media:

[image]

Any way to solve this?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Presumably this is a permission issue in the OS rather than anything intrinsic to R.

Comment: Linux Pop!_OS_21.04 based on Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: Note I have no problem selecting any folder when using Nautilus directly because I have the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the `...`. Then put in `/media`.

[image: screen shot]

Then you can navigate within the drive.

[image: second screen shot]

Or navigate to `/`.

Comment: By some reason, when I select ... I do not get the second menu that you reproduce here. Just the 1st one again.